# How to make the most relevant search with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I want to do a search based on its relevance to MySQL. Whatever I tried, I could not succeed. I did a Fulltext search, I did a search with Like, again I can not do the following order.

Search word for example this: "**first second**"

`First Second` Keyword ->  ***(full word) will begin with***
Keyword `First Second` Keyword -> ***(full word) in between or at the end***

`Firstsecond` Keyword ->  ***(adjacent word) will begin with***
Keyword `Firstsecond` Keyword ->  ***(adjacent word) in between or at the end***

`First` Keyword ->  ***(only the first word) will begin with***
Keyword `First` Keyword ->  ***(only the first word)  in between or at the end***

`Second` Keyword ->  ***(only the second word) will begin with***
Keyword `Second` Keyword ->  ***(only the second word)  in between or at the end***

---

***Then I want it to continue as below; (all of them)***

**First**asdasd Keyword
Keyword asdasd**first** Keyword
Keyword asdasd**first**asdasd Keyword

**Second**asdasd Keyword
Keyword asdasd**second** Keyword
Keyword asdasd**second**asdasd Keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, FULLTEXT won't do this kind of search. It's word-oriented.

What you want isn't really simple SQL. I think you want something like this to hit the first keyword.

```
SET @match := 'first'
SELECT MIN(priority) priority, value
  FROM (
      SELECT 1 priority, value FROM tbl WHERE value LIKE CONCAT(@match, ' %')
       UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 priority, value FROM tbl WHERE value LIKE CONCAT('% ', @match, ' %')
       UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 priority, value FROM tbl WHERE value LIKE CONCAT('%', @match, '%')
  ) results
 GROUP BY value
 ORDER BY MIN(priority), value;
```

Generally, you use a UNIONed series of SELECTs with priorities for the full-word and embedded word matches, and take the lowest priority match you get for each row.

You'll need to elaborate on that general kind of pattern to handle both keywords. This looks like it could turn into a real pain in the xxx neck to get right. And the `LIKE '%something'` search terms mean it won't be very fast.

If you're going to large scale with this, it might be worth investigating [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. The code you provided works very well.

Well, if I want to add other variables to the following query, so as an example;

Like "**city_id = 82 and status = 1 and (id = 5 or id = 9)**"

How can I add this query? Do I need to add it to all fields or is there another way?

Comment: Are you using version 8+ or 10+ of MariaDB? If so you can use [Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) (CTEs) to make your queries less verbose.